# How can I fix this ErrImagePull error in this Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Docker pull works fine. But I am getting this additional error
`rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit`

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. From the [docker documentation](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits)

> On November 20, 2020, rate limits anonymous and free authenticated use of Docker Hub went into effect. Anonymous and Free Docker Hub users are limited to 100 and 200 container image pull requests per six hours.

You have hit this limit.

You can either:

- Reduce your pull rate.
- Upgrade your membership.
- Setup your own docker proxy to cache containers locally

Of course, it may be as simple as changing your `imagePullPolicy` from `Always` to `IfNotPresent`